# How ssl client in gsoap can send only TLSv1 request to server

Tags: ssl, gsoap

I am using gSoap 2.8.16 version.
I recently upgraded my openssl at client to 1.0.2d version. But still I have soap server with openssl 1.0.0 version.

I am finding protocol version fatal error due to TLS version mismatch in client and server.
So I want SSL client in gsoap to send TLSv1 to the server.

I tried use like this, but client still sending TLSv1.2 version

```
soap_ssl_client_context(soap,SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION|SOAP_TLSv1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may want to upgrade gSOAP to a more recent version. The SOAP_TLSv1 flag works well in recent releases that include updates for the OpenSSL 1.0.x APIs as I saw in the [changelog](http://www.genivia.com/changelog.html).